# why is it printing 255

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
int main()
{

     unsigned char a = -1;
     printf("%d",a);
     printf("%u",a);
}
```

when i have executed the above program i got 255 255 as the answer.

we know negative numbers will be stored in 2's complement.

since it is 2's complement the representation would be
`1111 1111` -->2's complement.

but in the above we are printing `%d(int)` but integer is four bytes.

my assumption is even though it is character we are forcing compiler to treat it as integer.
so it internally uses sign extension concept.

`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`.

according to the above representation it has to be -1 in the first case since it is %d(signed).
in the second case it has to print (2^31- 1) but it is printing 255 and 255.
why it is printing 255 in both cases.
tell me if my assumption is wrong and give me the real interpretation.

Comment: @Shokwav is right, padded with 0 since it's unsigned; good question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to the representation of `a`, you are correct. However, the `%d` and `%u` conversions of the `printf()` function both take an `int` as an argument. That is, your code is the same as if you had written

```
int main() {
     unsigned char a = -1;
     printf("%d", (int)a);
     printf("%u", (int)a);
}
```

In the moment you have assigned `-1` to `a` you have lost the information that it once was a signed value, the logical value of `a` is `255`. Now, when you convert an `unsigned char` to an `int`, the compiler preserves the logical value of `a` and the code prints `255`.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is wrong; the character will "roll over" to 255, then be padded to the size of an integer. Assuming a 32-bit integer:

11111111

would be padded to:

00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111

Comment: but in case of signed char it is printing -1 and (2^31-1)..but in case of unsigned the answer is different

Comment: It is not `2^32-1` because you are not printing `-1`, you are printing `a`, and `a` is an `unsigned char` of value 255. If `a` was signed it would probably convert as -1, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned char` runs from `0-255` So the negative number `-1` will print `255` `-2` will print `254` and so on...

`signed char` runs from `-128 to +127` so you get -1 for the same `printf()` which is not the case with `unsigned char`

Once you make a assignment to a char then the rest of the integer values will be padded so your assumption of `2^31` is wrong.

The negative number is represented using 2's complement(Implementation dependent)

So

```
1 = 0000 0001
```

So in order to get `-1` we do

```
----------------------------------------
2's complement      = 1111 1111 = (255) |
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know what type the extra parameters in `printf` *should* be, since the only thing that specifies it should be treated as a 4-byte `int` is the format string, which is irrelevant at compile time.

What actually happens behind the scenes is the callee (`printf`) receives a pointer to each parameter, then casts to the appropriate type.

Roughly the same result as this:

```
char a = -1;
int * p = (int*)&a; // BAD CAST

int numberToPrint = *p; // Accesses 3 extra bytes from somewhere on the stack
```

Since you're likely running on a little endian CPU, the 4-byte `int` 0x12345678 is arranged in memory as `| 0x78 | 0x56 | 0x34 | 0x12 |`

If the 3 bytes on the stack following `a` are all `0x00` (they probably are due to stack alignment, but it's NOT GUARANTEED), the memory looks like this:

```
&a:       | 0xFF |
(int*)&a: | 0xFF | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
```

which evaluates to `*(int*)&a == 0x000000FF`.

Comment: In case of signed char it is printing -1 and (2^31-1)..but in case of unsigned the answer is different

Answer (score 0):

It is printing 255, simply because this is the purpose from ISO/IEC9899

> H.2.2 Integer types
>
> 1 The signed C integer types int, long int, long long int, and the corresponding
> unsigned types are compatible with LIA−1. If an implementation adds support for the
> LIA−1 exceptional values ‘‘integer_overflow’’ and ‘‘undefined’’, then those types are
> LIA−1 conformant types. C’s unsigned integer types are ‘‘modulo’’ in the LIA−1 sense
> in that overflows or out-of-bounds results silently wrap. An implementation that defines
> signed integer types as also being modulo need not detect integer overflow, in which case,
> only integer divide-by-zero need be detected.

If this is given, printing 255 is absolutly that, what the LIA-1 would expect.

Otherwise, if your implementation doesn't support C99's LIA-1 Annex part, then its simply undefined behaving.